# Difficulties getting 'Worksheetfunction.Index' to work (Excel 2010)

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, excel-2010

I'm trying to get a macro running with the index command in VBA. It is about a Risk variable in a riskmatrix, based on a 'chance' and 'effect' variable. I'm creating a tool that helps my organization perform risk assessments.

The user gives inputs for the chance and effect variables (X and Y axis). The sum should be selected from the matrix based on this input. The Matrix is created on a different sheet.

So far I got this:

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("RisicoMatrix")

Dim effectIniVar As Long
Dim waarschijnlijkheidIniVar As Long
Dim risicoIniVar As Long

effectIniVar = WorksheetFunction.Match(comboIniEffect, ws2.Range("A3:A10"), 0)

waarschijnlijkheidIniVar = WorksheetFunction.Match(comboIniWaarschijnlijkheid, ws2.Range("B2:I2"), 0)

risicoIniVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws2.Range("b3:I10"), effectIniVar, waarschijnlijkheidIniVar)
```

The first two Match commands work fine and give me the correct values, but the index line does not work. When I run the macro I get a runtime-13 error, a Type Mismatch error,  and the 'index' line is highlighted when I debug. I know there is probably not much correct about this line, but I don't understand the examples I have found on the forums.

I want to accomplish this in VBA because this is Macro is run from a form field. The risk matrix is just one of the elements there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: You appear to have misspelled `Match` on the second instance. Beyond that, you need to give more information than "does not work" please.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The typo-o slipped in when copying it to the post. what does not work is: It gives 'runtime-13 > type mismatch' error and the 'index' line is marked yellow when I debug. I know that the line is wrong. My question is: How can I apply 'index' in VBA without using 'Match'?

Comment: Then I suggest you fix the code and clarify what **exactly** you mean by "does not work". ;)

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I need help fixing the code, as I do not understand how to use 'index' works in general within VBA. I explained what 'does not work' means. I got runtime error 13.

Comment: I meant fix the typo in your question, and add the additional information there. A Type Mismatch error would suggest the value being returned cannot be coerced to a Long data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm much with Rory about returned value not implicitly convertible to a `Long` type.

Either you step through your code and see what value is being returned by `Index(ws2.Range("b3:I10"), effectIniVar, waarschijnlijkheidIniVar)`

or you put there an error handler, mostly (I believe) for debugging purposes

moreover `Match()` function can have some "side" effects as long as "numbers" vs "strings" matching is concerned, that can be most effectively be handled with `Find()` method of the `Range` object

so you could go like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main2()
    Dim effectIniVar As Long
    Dim waarschijnlijkheidIniVar As Long
    Dim risicoIniVar As Long
    Dim comboIniEffect As String, comboIniWaarschijnlijkheid As String '<--| just a guess
    Dim myVal As Variant '<--| variable to hold value returned by Index function

    comboIniEffect = 3 '<--| following on my guess
    comboIniWaarschijnlijkheid = "D" '<--| following on my guess

    With Worksheets("RisicoMatrix")
        If Not FindIndex(.Range("A3:A10"), comboIniEffect, "R", effectIniVar) Then Exit Sub '<--| try finding the row match, otherwise exit
        If Not FindIndex(.Range("B2:I2"), comboIniWaarschijnlijkheid, "C", waarschijnlijkheidIniVar) Then Exit Sub '<--| try finding the column match, otherwise exit
        myVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(.Range("b3:I10"), effectIniVar, waarschijnlijkheidIniVar) '<--| get value by Index function
        On Error GoTo errorhandler '<--| set your error handler
        risicoIniVar = CLng(myVal) '<--| try forcing value returned by Index into a Long type
        On Error GoTo 0 '<--| resume standard error handling
    End With

    MsgBox effectIniVar & ", " & waarschijnlijkheidIniVar & ", " & risicoIniVar '<--| if everything has worked, then show: row, column and value
    Exit Sub

errorhandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "while forcing '" & myVal & "' into a Long" '<--| show error conditions
End Sub


Function FindIndex(rng As Range, val As Variant, rowOrCol As String, index As Long) As Boolean
    Dim found As Range

    With rng
        Set found = .Find(what:=val, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            FindIndex = True
            index = IIf(UCase(rowOrCol) = "R", found.Row - .Rows(1).Row + 1, found.Column - .Columns(1).Column + 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your informative and extensive reply. I converted all the variables to strings and worked. I will look more into your code to understand what you are exactly suggesting. Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome. If you find I answered your needs then mark my answer as accepted. thank you